# Can I create a live wallpaper with flutter?

Tags: flutter, live-wallpaper

I have already created a live wallpaper in Kustom Live Wallpaper (KLWP) android app. It shows much helpful information.
But I need to use the KLWP app to run my live wallpaper. Is there any way to **build an app with flutter that can provide live wallpaper with information?**

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 1):

Just use this plugin `wallpaper_manager: ^1.0.10`

```
import 'package:wallpaper_manager/wallpaper_manager.dart';

dependencies:
  ...
  flutter:
    ...
    assets:
    - assets/tmp1.gif

String assetPath = "assets/tmp1.gif";
int location = WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN; // or location = WallpaperManager.LOCK_SCREEN;
String result;
final String result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromAsset(assetPath, location);
```